# En el submenú poner los <li> en la misma fila y si no caben, poner en una fila debajo

Tags: html, css, li, submenu

Tengo un menú, y lo que busco es en el submenú que tiene etiquetas `<li>` que se vean todas en una misma fila (creo que es con `display: inline-block` cierto? Y que cuando ya no caben en la misma fila, que se posicionen en otra fila justo debajo.

¿Cual seria el css?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor inserta tu código para poder ayudarte ya que no entiendo nada a lo que te referís también estaría bueno que insertes una captura de lo que ya generaste y que queres lograr con tu pedido.

Answer (score 0):

Agregar un `float: left` a tu elemento `<li>` debiese hacer el truco.

Te dejo un ejemplo

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: #333;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Opción</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Opción</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li href="#">Link 1</li>
      <li href="#">Link 2</li>
      <li href="#">Link 3</li>
      <li href="#">Link 4</li>
      <li href="#">Link 5</li>
      <li href="#">Link 6</li>
      <li href="#">Link 7</li>
      <li href="#">Link 8</li>
      <li href="#">Link 9</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```